# Unhashable type error: list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a piece of text and I am trying to list all of the countries mentioned in the text using the wikipedia-iso countries csv list as reference. I have loaded and split the text into a list of words, and loaded the wikipedia csv file and converted the required column to a set with the idea of iterating through both lists and printing a country if it appears in both lists but I am getting the unhashable error, below is my code:

```
text = pd.read_sql(select_string, con)
ftext = text['SomeText'].str.split()
country_codes = pd.read_csv('wikipedia-iso-country-codes.csv')
ccs = set(country_codes['English short name lower case'])
for country in ftext:
    if country in ccs:                  #this is where the error occurs
       print(country+'  is in the text')
```

As far as I can tell, the line:"if country in ccs:" is where the error occurs. Any help would be most appreciated...thanks.

Comment: How does `ftext` look like? The error occurs because `country` is a list.

Comment: ftext is a series object, Do I need to convert country to something else?

Comment: `country` should be a string, yes. Right now it's a list, which isn't hashable, so you can't put it in a set.

Comment: But there is no explicit declaration of country so how do I control its type?

Comment: Well, you can first of take a look at it, by printing country in the for loop before the condition. And then you could say something like `country = country[0]` if the first element of that list is what you want.

Comment: Yes but if you make that assignment in the for loop then for each word in ftext it just replaces it with the assignment country[0] which is nothing so the if statement will always evaluate to nothing too.

Comment: ...just tell me what `country` is within the loop.

Comment: country is just a word - for word in text: if word in anothertext ..... So if a word in the text like France also happens to be in the country's list then do something...